# Writing ElementTree compressed in gzip format

Tags: python, gzip, elementtree

I'm trying to write a spcific subtree of my xml in `gzip` format. The following `Python` code writes a regular xml to file and I'm not sure how to add compression to it

```
import os, time, gzip
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.cElementTree import ElementTree

. . . 

ElementTree(child).write('outputFile.xml')
```

I'd like to write a file `outputFile.xml.gz` that can be opened with common applications. Keep in mind that I'm new to Python...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ElementTree.write() can be passed a file object opened for writing.

```
import os, time, gzip
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.cElementTree import ElementTree

. . . 

f = gzip.open('/home/joe/file.txt.gz', 'wb')
ElementTree(child).write(f) 
f.close()
```

From http://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html and http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.

Comment: thanks Vortexfive, but do you know how I can write and compress an ElementTree specifically? 'ElementTree(child)' seems not to be a valid 'content' for the gzip library

Comment: I noticed that a moment too late. I think I edited the answer correctly so that you can use it to write ElementTrees now.

Comment: Awesome! I thought that it would have been about some sort of decoration, thanks!